# How to start using Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have a working web app which can do search for `User` objects through its `Username`. I wonder if I can use Hibernate-Search to do a text search through all of the User object attributes, like its:

- Username, Full Name, Address, etc.

And will output User objects with attributes that matches the search query?

Also is there any thing that is needed to be annotated in the `User` class in my application?

User.java:

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    private String username;
    private String fullname;
    private String address;
    // Code omitted

    public User() {

    }
    // Getters & setters omitted
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you read the documentation? http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search/docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
My answer belongs to the original question. Please don't modify a question this way. Ask another one, if another problem occurs:

> How to start using Hibernate Search? I have a working web app which
>   can do search for User objects through its Username. I wonder if I can
>   use Hibernate-Search to do a text search through all of the User
>   object attributes, like its:
>
> Username, Full Name, Address, etc. And will output User objects with
>   attributes that matches the search query?
>
> Also is there any thing that is needed to be annotated in the User
>   class in my application?

I start with googling:

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hibernate+search

and reading the documentation like this:

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html-single/Hibernate_Search_Reference_Guide/index.html

Comment: The question seems to be modified after I wrote my answer.